# Check whether activerecord field is a substring of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I know how to check if a query is a substring of a field:

`where("field like ?", query)`

But how would I do it in reverse? So that it checks if a field is a substring of the query?

E.g. if I have objects:

`[123,45,678]`

I want to know which ones occur in the number:

`45678` = `[45,678]`

My current solution is:

```
mer = []    
Mer14.find_each do |m| 
  if query.include?(m.sequence)
    mer << m
  end
```

But I'm not sure if this is efficient or ideal!

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the arguments

```
where("? LIKE field", query)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, it returns an empty array. I've edited my code with my current solution, but I'm not sure it's ideal.